# JavaFX checking if Event's KeyCode is a digit key

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm creating a custom textfield class in which i have a custom behaviour depending on if the user types digit keys on it.

`!event.getCode().isDigitKey()`  always returns true, even when i type digits. I tried to check if KeyCode is a letter also and still it returns false. What seems to be the issue here?

I always get false when checking the **event's KeyCode** against any **other KeyCode**, even when they should be equal.

```
public class ScoreField extends TextField implements Customizable {

public ScoreField() {
    super();
    customize();
}

@Override
public void customize() {
    this.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        int curChar = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            event.consume();
            KeyCode keyTyped  = event.getCode();
            char    charTyped = event.getCharacter().charAt(0);

            System.out.println(charTyped);

            // Do nothing if not a digit
            if (!event.getCode().isDigitKey()) {
                System.out.println("NOT A DIGIT KEY");
                if (keyTyped == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
                    System.out.println("RESETTING");
                    resetText();
                    return;
                }
                return;
            }

            if (getText().length() >= 5) {
                if (curChar == 2) {
                    curChar = 3;
                }
                if (curChar == 5) {
                    curChar = 0;
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(getText());
                builder.setCharAt(curChar, charTyped);
                setText(builder.toString());
                curChar++;
                return;
            }
            if (getText().length() == 2) {
                setText(getText() + ":");
            }
            setText(getText() + charTyped);
        }
    });
}

private void resetText() {
    setText("");
}
```

}

Comment: See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html). For key typed events, the code is always `KeyCode.UNDEFINED`. Use `getCharacter()` and check if it's a digit with string methods, or use a key pressed event.

Comment: I would probably not use event handlers for this at all, fwiw, but would use a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) instead (depending, I suppose, on the exact nature of your "special behavior").

Comment: I updated the code to include the behavior. I don't think TextFormatter will do my job, looking at its docs.

Comment: I guess i'll just do a `if (("" + charTyped).matches("[0-9]"))` for a get around, for now, Since the keycode is always UNDEFINED.

Comment: Why not `if (Character.isDigit(charTyped))`?

Comment: That's a lot neater thanks! If you'd want to answer the question so i can accept it. I still don't get why they chose to make the KeyCode return undefined for the keytyped event

Comment: I still think you should be using a `TextFormatter` here, but I can't quite figure out what your code is trying to do.

Comment: It's basically setting a timer in this format mm:ss [minutes and seconds] as the user types. If he made a mistake he can either press press backspace to clear the text or continue typing and replace each already typed digit with the newly typed key[if the max length of digits (5) is met]

Comment: That's pretty much exactly the use case for a `TextFormatter`.

Comment: That would be nice, if i was able to do it in a neater way. I'll try to get it to work with the TextFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

As James_D stated:

> For key typed events, the code is always KeyCode.UNDEFINED

So i did as he suggested and instead of checking the KeyCode if it's a digit, i checked `event.getCharacter()[0]` using `Character.isDigit(char)` in the 1ST if statement, and it worked perfectly for my case.

P.S: I tried to use a TextFormatter with a StringConverter, but i couldn't get it to work.

Comment: James_D didn't suggest using the converter of the `TextFormatter` to do this, but [the filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#getFilter--) allowing you to modify the result of the input before the text of the `TextField` is modified.